# C# equivalent of Java `<F extends FieldType<?>> void add(F field)`

Tags: c#, generic-programming

I am very new to C#, sorry if someone already asked that question, I didn't found any answer.

The question is clear in the title so here's the code I'm trying to achieve :

```
/// <typeparam name="M">Entity model</typeparam>
public class FormBuilder<M>
{

    /// <typeparam name="F">Implementation of FieldType</typeparam>
    public FormBuilder<M> Add<F>(string propertyName, F options) where F : FieldType<?>
    {
        // ...
        return this;
    }

}

/// <typeparam name="T">Type of the field</typeparam>
public abstract class FieldType<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public bool Disabled { get; set; } = false;
    public bool Required { get; set; } = true;
    public string Hint { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> Attributes { get; set; }
}

public class TextType : FieldType<string>
{
    public bool Trim { get; set; } = true;
    public string Placeholder { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since C#'s generics are *reified* whereas Java uses *type erasure* to implement its generics, there are some fundamental differences that crop up in certain edge cases like this one. Long story short: you need to have an actual generic type specified for `FieldType<>`. The good news is that you can do this via generics.

```
public FormBuilder<M> Add<F, T>(string propertyName, F options) where F : FieldType<T>
{
    // ...
    return this;
}
```

Of course, you'll want to consider whether you really need the `F` generic type at all. Depending on what you're doing, it's likely you can get away with something more straightforward:

```
public FormBuilder<M> Add<T>(string propertyName, FieldType<T> options)
{
    // ...
    return this;
}
```

Comment: I do not know if I understand correctly, does it means that I need to explicitly specify `builder.Add<TextType, string>(..., new TextType  {` ? It is possible to avoid redundancy ? Thank  you very much

Comment: @dctremblay: C#'s type inference takes care of figuring out that `T` is `string`. Just call `builder.Add(..., new TextType{...})`.